# JSP XML syntax error: JasperException when replacing <% %> with <jsp:scriptlet> </jsp:scriptlet>

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

The following code in a jsp file displays a web page using Apache Tomcat with no problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<%@page import='java.util.*' %>
<%@page contentType='text/html' pageEncoding='UTF-8' %>
<html>
    <body>
        <%
            ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
            stringList.add("string A");
            stringList.add("string B");
            for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++){
            out.println("<p>"+stringList.get(i)+"</p>");
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

But this code which uses XML syntax throws a JasperException, even though it is the same as the above, just replacing the JSP tags with JSP XML tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<jsp:directive.page import='java.util.*' />
<jsp:directive.page contentType='text/html' pageEncoding='UTF-8' />
<html>
    <body>
        <jsp:scriptlet>
            ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
            stringList.add("string A");
            stringList.add("string B");
            for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++){
                out.println("<p>"+stringList.get(i)+"</p>");
            }
        </jsp:scriptlet>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which throws this error:

```
Aug 22, 2013 2:27:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [/cftp2Error.jsp (line: 6, column: 17) Unterminated &lt;jsp:scriptlet&gt; tag] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /cftp2Error.jsp (line: 6, column: 17) Unterminated &lt;jsp:scriptlet&gt; tag
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:408)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:133)
...
```

Could anyone please tell me where I am going wrong with my XML JSP code? I'm running JDK1.7 with Tomcat 7.0.34.
Thanks,
Keith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the file contents in `<jsp:root></jsp:root>` and also escape the < and > characters, something like:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
```

```
        ArrayList&lt;String&gt; stringList = new ArrayList&lt;String&gt;();
        stringList.add("string A");
        stringList.add("string B");
        for (int i = 0; i &lt; stringList.size(); i++){
            out.println("<p>"+stringList.get(i)+"</p>");
        }

    </jsp:scriptlet>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I didn't know about the jsp:root tag. I searched that term and found that JSP XML syntax is not made for hand coding (source: http://www.coderanch.com/t/475967/JSP/java/Strange-JSP-error-Invalid-Standard) , which is a pity. Even with the jsp:root tag I can not get the page to work, but at least I now know that this XML style of writing jsp pages will be fraught with problems.

Comment: I think the key is to escape the < and > characters. Can you try the same now, because I'm able to get the page up with a tomcat instance

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. Yes I tried it with those escape characters and it made no difference. I even tried using an array instead of the ArrayList, and removed the <p> elements from the string and still it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. (Note:and Iterate an arraylist with iterator.)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<jsp:directive.page import='java.util.*' />
<jsp:directive.page contentType='text/html' pageEncoding='UTF-8' />
<html>
    <body>
        <jsp:declaration>
            ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
            stringList.add("string A");
            stringList.add("string B");
            for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++){
                out.println("<p>"+stringList.get(i)+"</p>");
            }
        </jsp:declaration>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it throwing the same exception ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the tag   which is JSP XML syntax should not be used for hand-coding (unlike the <% %> tags, as I found out on this page: 
http://www.coderanch.com/t/475967/JSP/java/Strange-JSP-error-Invalid-Standard

Getting the code to work properly would require lots of effort to convert all entity characters (<, >, &, etc) to their escaped versions and would require lots of additional XML tags to make it acceptable jsp XML markup.
Cheers,
Keith